# Real Hadamard powers of matrices

Tags: matrices, hadamard-product, matrix-analysis

Let $A$ be an entrywise nonnegative matrix and for any $r>0$, $A^{\circ r} = [a_{ij}^{r}]$. My question is what properties of matrix $A$ are preserved for all $r>0$ or for all $r$ in some interval ? For example : if I want to show the matrix $A^{\circ r}$ is nonsingular for all or some $r$, how can I proceed such type of questions ? Are there any integral, summation, product or limits formulae for the function $x \rightarrow x^{r}$ for all $x \in (0,\infty)$ and a fixed $r>0$, which can be applicable for such kind of questions.  
Same questions are for the matrix $B = \int_{a}^{b} a_{ij}(t)$, where $A(t) = [a_{ij}(t)]$ is a given matrix for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Any important relative links for books or papers or examples will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the definition of $x^{\circ r}$ when $x$ is a real number?

Comment: Sorry, its a function from $(0,\infty)$. Thanks for replying.

Comment: So what kind of function is $x\mapsto x^{\circ r}$ for $x>0$?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. I am just taking entrywise powers of the matrix $A$. Like if $r$ is a positive integer, then $A^{\circ r}$ are Hadamard product of $A$ with itself.

Comment: I was referring to your definition  $$A^{\circ r} = [a_{ij}^{{\color{red}\circ} r}]\,.$$  Now, I assume the red circle thing is a typo, since you said you are only taking entrywise powers?

Comment: Oh yes, thanks, It's edited now.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$  entrywise nonnegative matrix that is also PSD and let $\alpha$ be a real number.

If $\alpha\geq n-2$, then  $A^{o\alpha}$ is PSD; moreover $n-2$ is the best bound. cf.

Fitzgerald, Horn: "On fractional Hadamard powers of PSD matrices".